# How to get the selected page index of ViewPager in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm making use of [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), and I have my adapter defined like this:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
    IconPagerAdapter {

private final static String TAB_ITEMS[] = { "Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3", "Tab 4"};

private int count = TAB_ITEMS.length;

public MyPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new BaseFragment();

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
```

And this is my activity that will contain my fragments:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnPageChangeListener {

private int tabPosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter (
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    UnderlinePageIndicator indicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setFades(false);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
        int positionOffsetPixels) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setTabPosition(position);

    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
            "Changed to page: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void setTabPosition(int position) {
    this.tabPosition = position;
}

public int getTabPosition() {
    return this.tabPosition;
}
```

}

Finally the definition of `BaseFragment`:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
private final static String TAG = "BaseFragment";

private int tabPosition;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, container,
            false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    tabPosition = ((MyActivity) getActivity()).getTabPosition();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "page " + tabPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

}
```

Now , this is my problem:

The toast in `onPageSelected` of the activity always shows the correct page when a new page is selected or swiped to.

However, the toast in my fragment only shows the correct page when you swipe to either page 1 or page 2. The only time it toasts page 0 is anytime the app is launched. After that, when the user swipes to page 0 or page 4, no toast is shown at all, not even an empty toast.

I wrote the `getTabPosition()` and `setTabPosition()` methods with the intention of getting the current selected tab position in the fragment, but it obviously doesn't work correctly hence I dont get toasts on pages 0 and 4.

My question is: how do I get the selected page position in my `BaseFragment`, since I need that position to load the appropriate data?

Hope I was clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Fragment will display a different set of data, then maybe it is a good idea to have one fragment for each. Here is what I did to display different Fragments for different data in the **FragmentPagerAdapter**:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        // Define the page for each index
        switch(index){

            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                break;

        }
```

This may not be the best approach but in your activity that holds reference to ViewPager try this:

```
public class TabbedViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int tabIndex = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        ......
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        TabbedViewActivity.tabIndex = 0; // in the start index is always 0 unless coded otherwise
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                         TabbedViewActivity.tabIndex = position;

                    }
                });

}
```

Then you can always access this variable statically like this in your Fragment TabbedViewActivity.tabIndex

Comment: I haven't tried with constructor but I tried `setArguments()` and that didn't work either since that is "recommended instead of non-default constructors."

Comment: I also realised that in `getItem()` the activity always instantiates 2 instances of the fragment. So when I try your edited post, I get both indices 0 and 1 in my fragment.

Comment: It actually instantiates the first two so that swiping is fluid. Then when navigating to second tab, it will also generate the third beforehand. So that the next can also be seen quickly.

Comment: Yea, I understand that so how do you suggest I structure my code in order to get/know the current selected item in the fragment? That is if I want to still keep my one fragment

Comment: I edited again. Perhaps a change listener on the ViewPager which updates the position to a static variable will let you know the current index.

Comment: Same result as others: The toast shows on pages 1 and 2 but doesnt on pages 0 and 4. Meanwhile, the toast in `onPageSelected()` always shows. Why is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68084/discussion-between-zakimak-and-nii-laryea).

Answer (score 0):

```
             pager.getCurrentItem();
```

it return current fragment index

Comment: I tried that in place of `tabPosition = ((MyActivity) getActivity()).getTabPosition();`, like so: `tabPosition = ((MyActivity) getActivity()).pager.getCurrentItem();` but same results. Swiping to the first and last pages don't show the toast.